# Freezing certain filters in pre-trained model, Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

Is it possible to load a pre-trained model, say ResNet152, and then to freeze certain weights within particular layers and fine-tune the others within those particular layer? For example:

**Say, freeze 50% of filters in a particular conv layer, and fine-tune the remaining 50% in that same particular conv layer?**

I can't seem to think of a solid way to implement this. I thought perhaps load the pre-trained model twice, freeze the one and allow the other to fine-tune, but then I'd need to remove filters from both branches.

Answer (score 0):

You can freeze the layers using `layer.trainable = False` (in Tensorflow or Keras). After you train your network and want to finetune it. You can use something like the following to freeze some of your weights:

```
for layer in model.layers[:5]: # freeze first 5 layers 
    layer.trainable = False
```

[Docpage](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/transfer_learning#freezing_layers_understanding_the_trainable_attribute)

Comment: Sorry I meant, to freeze weights within one layer. For example, to freeze 16 filters from a conv layer which contains 32 filters.